# Anomaly detection on time series

Tags: machine-learning, python, time-series, unsupervised-learning, anomaly-detection

I've just started working on an anomaly detection development in Python.

My data sets are a collection of timeseries. More in details, data are coming from some sensors/meters which record and collect data on boilers or other equipments.

As I said before, the data which I have to work with, are timeseries, so a timestamp and the relative value detected by sensor; a value is anomalous when it's bigger or smaller than the others near it; basically a peak.

I need to develop an unsupervised classification model, because I haven't labels for all data.

Another important aspect, is that this data are "season dependent"; in fact a boiler should be has a higher consumptions in winter than summer. Those values must not be considered as anomalies.

Since I've no experince on this topic, I'm here to ask you, what is the best algorithm/approace to solve this problem.

Furthermore, do you know some books or links to suggest?

Comment: Please provide a graph (real units do not matter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For understanding the seasonality of time series data I would start with Holt-Winters Method or ARIMA. Understanding these algorithms will help with understand how time series forecasting works. 
[Time series forecasting](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/02/time-series-forecasting-methods/)

For unsupervised classification, I would start with something like k-means clustering for anomaly detection.
[Anomaly Detection with K-Means Clustering](http://amid.fish/anomaly-detection-with-k-means-clustering)

These links should be a good starting point, I hope this helps.

Comment: As a general notice, there has been comprehensive research that prooves **clustering subsequences in time-series** is meaningless. The work that is linked here also has a reference to this piece of research. So I believe this approach could not be a good starting point as it is proved to be absurd. I found [algorithms in Luminol's library](https://github.com/linkedin/luminol/tree/master/src/luminol/algorithms/anomaly_detector_algorithms) much suited as a starting point for anomaly detection.

Comment: @NovinShahroudi, could you go into detail as on why this is meaningless, or provide a link? Can't find it in OP's question...

Comment: @Thomas you can find it here: http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/meaningless.pdf

Answer (score 5):

You can have a look [here](https://github.com/rob-med/awesome-TS-anomaly-detection), where many open-source algorithms specifically for **anomaly detection on time-series data** (e.g. metrics) are collected, both for online of offline settings.

Almost all of them are **unsupervised approaches** that require no labels to detect the anomalies.

They also automatically handle some of the issues you mentioned, like **seasonality**.

Answer (score 0):

About anomalies detection, you have a bunch of methods. In the jargon they are called outliers, and [Wikipedia's Outlier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlier) article is a very good start.

Most answers from Time Series will advise to use an Exponential smoothing (in the Holt-Winters version to take care of the seasonality), or the *ARIMA (of which Exponential smoothing is a individual case).

This may be good. However, for situation like this, Engineers are used to filter the sensor with a Kalman filter. The mathematical step is steeper, though.